# How can I schedule a batch for every 2h (to run at half past?)

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

How can I schedule a batch every 2h (to run at half past?) like..

```
00.30, 2.30, 4.30, 6.30, ..... 20.30
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, CRON expression allows to specify minutes and hours of the job.
For minutes, it is possible to specify at which minute of an hour job should be run.
For hours, hours can be specified via enumeration (`2,4,6`) or via once per how many hours (`*/2`).

Taking that into account, following CRON expression can be used:

`0 30 */2 * * ?`

`0 30 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20 * * ?`

`0 30 0-20/2 * * ?`

(Last two if 22.30 run should be skipped)

Comment: Thanks, they work! I have not to skip 22.30 (I had an error in the message), thanks anyway for indicating both methods ;)